# Convert AutoMapperMappingException To JSON

Tags: json.net, automapper

In trying to troubleshoot some code, I looked to the log where I am capturing any unhandled exceptions.

In my log function, I have the following line of code:

```
data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(exception)
```

Part of the value of data reads, \"Message\":null.  When I debug and look at the exception, the Message property of the exception has a value (which accurately describes the issue).  If I try to convert a different exception to JSON using the line above, I see the value of the Message property in the resulting JSON.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in [`AutoMapperMappingException`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/AutoMapperMappingException.cs).  Json.NET supports [`ISerializable`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ISerializable), and the base class [`System.Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implements this interface.  As can be seen from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,fc1dcb30e55ae2d7,references), the base class version of [`GetObjectData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) simply adds the *base field value* not the *property value* to the serialization stream:

```
        info.AddValue("Message", _message, typeof(String));
```

Any subclass of `Exception` that holds additional data above and beyond the base class must needs override `GetObjectData` and serialize its own data.  For instance, here is the implementation of [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/argumentoutofrangeexception.cs,3d513676819217d4,references):

```
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        if (info==null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        info.AddValue("ActualValue", m_actualValue, typeof(Object));
    }
```

Now, from its [source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/AutoMapperMappingException.cs), `AutoMapperMappingException` overrides [`Exception.Message`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to output additional data.  And in fact, the base message might be null:

```
    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            string message = null;
            var newLine = Environment.NewLine;
            if (Context != null)
            {
                message = _message + newLine + newLine + "Mapping types:";
                message += newLine + string.Format("{0} -> {1}", Context.SourceType.Name, Context.DestinationType.Name);
                message += newLine + string.Format("{0} -> {1}", Context.SourceType.FullName, Context.DestinationType.FullName);

                var destPath = GetDestPath(Context);
                message += newLine + newLine + "Destination path:" + newLine + destPath;

                message += newLine + newLine + "Source value:" + newLine + (Context.SourceValue ?? "(null)");

                return message;
            }
            if (_message != null)
            {
                message = _message;
            }

            message = (message == null ? null : message + newLine) + base.Message;

            return message;
        }
    }
```

It *does not*, however, override `GetObjectData()`, which is the bug.

To work around the problem, you could write your own custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) and serialize the message property instead of the base field:

```
public class ExceptionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(AutoMapperMappingException).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var exception = (Exception)value;
        var obj = JObject.FromObject(exception);
        obj["Message"] = exception.Message;
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

This will at least ensure the message is present.  However, the [`ResolutionContext`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/ResolutionContext.cs) property of [`AutoMapperMappingException`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/AutoMapperMappingException.cs) still won't be serialized, so the resulting deserialized exception will have lost some data.

Alternatively, you could try serializing and deserializing the `ResolutionContext` with Json.NET's default serialization and adding it as a property in the converter.  Not sure if it would work, but it might.  Or try to [report an issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues).

(Or, just log the `ToString()` output of the exception, that's usually good enough.)